# enums in C# - assignment

Tags: c#, enums

How does one do this in c#?

Let's say that myclass has :

```
private enum Days{};
```

1)  How does one add data to the enum inside the myclass with the help of the constructor? As in :

```
myclass my = new myclass(Monday,Friday);
```

so that the enum inside the class gets the "Monday, Friday" properties.

2) Can one also make a property for an enume inside the class once it is initialized ? For example :

```
my.Days = new enum Days(Tuesday); //where the old settings are replaced.
```

EDIT:

What I want to do is following:

Have an enum in the main class, like enum Days{Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday};

I would also have something inside the myclass (enum?) so that I can assign some values from Days enum to myclass internal (enum?) with only some but not all of the values in the Days enum.

So that I can get a myclass which contains an (enum?) with "Monday,Tuesday", while some myclass222 contains (enum?) "Friday" etc.

I don't know if the enum is the correct way to do this inside the myclass classes ?

Comment: In the first line of code, do you mean that to be an array? 
"private enum Days[]; "

Comment: I meant that be an an empty enum. Once one creates the class the enum Days should be filled up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague, but if you are actually asking how to construct an enum where the values can be combined, the answer is to decorate it with the [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[Flags]
public enum Days
{
    None = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64
}
```

Now, if you have some member of the type `Days`, you can assign a combined value to it:

```
Days someDays = Days.Monday | Days.Wednesday;
```

**Update**
On request; here is how to check whether a certain value is set:

```
bool wednesdayIsSet = (someDays & Days.Wednesday) == Days.Wednesday;
```

In response to the question on how to create a member of the enum in one class when the enum is defined in another class, that would look like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Flags]
    public enum Days
    {
        None = 0,
        Monday = 1,
        // and so on
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public SomeClass.Days SomeDays { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 The code to know if a day is defined or not would be nice too. I believe it's not obvious for everybody.

Comment: That seems to be what I want to do. Question is, if enum Days is defined in my "main class", how can I have a member of Days inside another "myclass class" so that i can use myclass.someDays= Days.Monday ?

Comment: @Zka: The enum in myclass must be declared as public

Comment: @Zka: I updated my answer. @citronas: it does not necessarily need to be public, but it needs to be "visible" from the consuming class.

Comment: Oh how stupid of me.. Brain freeze. Thanks Fredrik it's all clear now

Answer (score 8):

1) You can't. The enum must be defined at compile time

It seems like you might look for an AttributeCollection instead. (have a look at Fredrik Mörk's answer, that it what I was trying to talk about ;) )

2) `my.Days = Days.Tuesday`

Answer (score 2):

Can't tell from the question, but maybe you intend something like this:

1. Define an enum with the days

   public enum Days
   {
       Sunday,
       Monday,
       .
       .
       .
   }
2. Create a list attribute of Days within your class
3. Add the required Days to your list when you need them

Answer (score 0):

> That seems to be what I want to do.
>   Question is, if enum Days is defined
>   in my "main class", how can I have a
>   member of Days inside another "myclass
>   class" so that i can use
>   myclass.someDays= Days.Monday ?

well assuming ur main class is mainClass and u have provided apt access perms, then depending on the definition of enum ie
1. If it is static then
   myclass.someDays = mainClass.Days.Monday;
2. else, u have to access it thru an object of mainClass
   mainClass mc = new mainClass();
   myclass.someDays = mc.Days.Monday;